# confidence interval methods for the mean are "robust against departures of normality"---does that refer to the population or sampling distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, robust-statistics

It is sometimes said that ***confidence interval methods for the mean are robust against departures of normality***.  But does this refer to the *population* distribution, or the *sampling* distribution (of the sample mean)?

For instance, the criterion $n\geqslant 30$ is often given as a kind of rule of thumb for using the $t$-distribution.  So in that case it doesn't matter very much what the population distribution is, as long as it's not too terribly wonky.  Is that what is meant by "robust against departures from normality"?  Maybe, but I suspect not.

My guess is that it's referring instead to the sampling distribution.  I am told, for instance, that even for "nice" distributions (e.g. the uniform of chi-square) this $n\geqslant 30$ condition sometimes only gives a very rough normal approximation in the sampling distribution.  But apparently it's still okay to use run the $t$-interval.  Is that what is meant when we are told that these methods are "robust against departures from normality"?

That's what I'm guessing, but I don't want to guess!  So, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I was taught $n\ge 30$ was a rule of thumb for using normal distribution tables rather than Student $t$-distribution tables, but then computers came along and this stopped mattering; all this assumed a sample from a normally distributed population.

Comment: With $95\%$ confidence intervals, it is always possible to invent a distribution which defeats your rule of thumb: suppose you have $P(X=0)=0.99$ and $P(X=1000)=0.01$: then it has mean $10$ but unless you have a sample size greater than $68$ then you confidence interval is more likely than not to fail to cover $10$

Comment: I think it's typically referring to the population distribution, see for example this paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2242772